# Search (sub/partial)string in text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-matching

I have a text and want to search few words in the text. For example the text in the form of string is:

`this is a sample string...`

and the word which I want to search is something like: `sample.json` so the `sample` should match in the string partially. And the output should be `sample`.
I am using `in` and `any` to match the strings but these condition don't work.

```
       if any(word.startswith(text.lower())):
       # do something
```

also tried this condition:

```
if word.lower() in text.lower():
        # do something
```

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should look for the algorithm of Longest common substring

Comment: thanks for the hint. Code is also given on this link: https://linuxhint.com/find-longest-common-substring-python/